# ng-click not being handled in custom ng-grid header

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added a button to my headers in the ng-grid with

```
<img class="dataWindowConfigButton" ng-click="foobar()"
```

and overridden the headerCellTemplate action with my html.

I have a foobar function in my controller but when I click on it still is doing the sort rather than calling my function.

Comment: Can you add a Plunker with your current setting?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/o0WjME?p=preview

Comment: I figured it out. I had the ng-click in the img tag, once I moved it to a div surrounding the img tag, it works.